# Как сделать номер телефона ссылкой для набора номера на мобильных?

Tags: android, html, ios, windows-phone-7

У меня на сайте есть страница [контакты](http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua/kontakty.html). Как мне сделать так, чтобы люди которые заходят с мобильных устройств iOS, Android и Windows Phone могли нажать на номер телефона, как на ссылку, и телефон сразу же начал звонить. Как это реализовать? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для айфона скорее всего достаточно будет указать в ссылке протокол tel, например, tel://+74952222222 . Скажу честно, никогда не пробовал делать это в htmlб, но, по идее, должно работать. Для других систем не в курсе.

Comment: Спасибо. на Андроиде работает, на других платформах пока нет возможности проверить...

Comment: Под iOS тоже работает. Только правильно будет "tel:+74952222222" (без //). Стандарт https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3966

Comment: На Windows Phone также работает.

Comment: Так я про айось и писал, про другие не в курсе был, если честно.